# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder referencing the local folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile snippet:

```
RUN mkdir sys_libs
COPY sys_lib/vs_log.rb sys_libs/vs_log.rb
```

The file does exist in the local ./sys_lib folder.

when I attempt to build: get:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder085599896/sys_lib/vs_log.rb: no such file or directory

Note the folder name referenced in the docker path is the name of the local folder, not the name of the docker folder just created.

I get the same if I do a `COPY sys_lib/ sys_libs/`

If I make the local and the docker folder the same I get the same thing:

```
RUN mkdir sys_lib
COPY sys_lib/ sys_lib/
```

I have tried it with leading./ and without on both sides.

I am out of options. Any ideas?

Comment: I am almost sure you are ignoring `sys_lib` (local) in your .dockerignore file (a.k.a. the folder is not part of the *context*).

Comment: I currently have no .dockerignore file, so that is not the cause.  Also why would it be referencing the local file associated with the temp image being created?

Comment: Could you show me the command you are using to build? Maybe you using a wrong context.

Comment: And regarding your question about the file referenced, */var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder085599896* is the context the docker daemon created to build the image. As we can see, the folder *sys_lib* was not sent to the context, or it is in another path.

Comment: docker build -t dhf0820/delivery-manager:latest -f ./delivery-manager/Dockerfile ./delivery-manager

the source folders have the ./sys_lib in it at the level the docker is being run.  The main app is and most of the code is in the delivery-manager folder that contains the docker file.  This is part of several processes that have man common libs and they are one level up (current folder)  ./sys_lib The real docker folder is also called sys_lib. I changed the name temporarily to see which was being referenced.  I get the same error if named properly.

Comment: Ok, you are telling docker your context is `./delivery-manager`. Does `sys_lib/` exist in `./sys_lib/` or `./delivery-manager/sys_lib/`?

Comment: It resides in ./sys_lib since it is used by several process that ar4e being created. The current directory has several other source folders line delivery-manager.

Comment: OK, I understand, but in that case the folder is out of the context. That is the problem...

Comment: is not the context the folder where the build is run from. I tried running it from the delivery-manager and of course, it failed with out of context error.

If I am doing it wrong, how do I generate the image with a common folder one level up from the main folder?

Comment: No, it is not, it is what you specify as the last argument in the `docker build` command.

Comment: In this case, what is the proper command and where is it executed from

Comment: I got the "proper" way that I followed from several sites like this:
https://www.jamestharpe.com/include-files-outside-docker-build-context/